# Angular electron mysql create conncetion is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, angular, typescript, node-mysql

I haveinstalled node js mysql and mysql types via

```
"@types/mysql": "^2.15.4",
"mysql": "^2.15.0"
```

Am using electron with angular2 so in my component i wanted to create a conncection via

```
import * as mysql from 'mysql'

 @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 })

 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    connection: any;
    constructor() {
       this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
           host: 'localhost',
           user: 'root',
           password: '5378@Geowan5378',
           database: 'company'
        });

    this.connection.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error connecting', err);
        }else{
            console.log("connection was a success ");
        }
    });

}   // DI
```

But now am getting an error

```
TypeError: o.createConnection is not a function
```

This is the only component so far as am only learning on electron and mysql. Where am i going wrong?

Note that the error happens when i call

```
this.connection.connect
```

I undestand that this may be caused by Net library which is not available in the browser but in my case am running `electron .` to launch my app so am not using the browser

Or how can i then connect the app directly with mysql without using a server side framework

Comment: Have you try to import mysql by doing const mysql = require('mysql') ?

Comment: this throws an error of unknown require

Comment: Mmmh if it is the function require that is undefined try  `declare const window; const mysql = window.require('mysql')` if its fail maybe mysql wrongly install https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/259/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-electron-framework

Answer (score 1):

You must use **remote** from Electron API to require mysql instead of using import.

1. Declare your remote global variable on index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>

<script>
var remote = require('electron').remote;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Use remote on app.component.ts

```js
declare var remote :any; // declare remote as any variable

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 })

 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    connection: any;
    constructor() {
      var mysql = remote.require('mysql'); //require mysql with electron remote
       this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
           host: 'localhost',
           user: 'root',
           password: '5378@Geowan5378',
           database: 'company'
        });

    this.connection.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error connecting', err);
        }else{
            console.log("connection was a success ");
        }
    });

}   // DI
```

Hope this helps, i suggest you improve the mysql loading method with service to make its efficient to make query etc.

Edit : or use my module https://github.com/mochrira/ngx-mysql and learn how to use it

Comment: i see thanks for the insight on remote.require it now works though i used a different way i used ngx-electron to handle the remote electron connection.

Comment: hii, i need help in 2 things 1. make ionic exe with electron 2. connect to db, i am ready for paid help. Please contact me at ersaurabh101@gmail.com , kindly mail me and ping me for chat on same address...thanks